# WPF Toolkit DataGrid MultiSelect with MVVM

Tags: mvvm, wpftoolkit, viewmodel, multi-select

We're using the WPF DataGrid from the WPF Toolkit and are employing MVVM. I'm finding some challenges in using MultiSelect in MVVM and am sure that I'm just missing something simple. I can use the "IsSelected" in the ViewModel to get the event when selecting a row in the DataGrid. This works fine for a single selection.

If I set "SelectionMode=Extended" I still only get the event on the selection of the first row in the DataGrid.SelectionChanged in the codebehind gets each selection event but I really want to make this work in the ViewModel. There is probably a simple solution to this multiSelect that I am just missing. I also tried binding SelectedItems (plural) to a collection to get all of these, but SelectedItems is readonly so it can't be bound to. I sure would appreciate any ideas on how to do this as I can't get this method moved from the codebehind to the ViewModel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to the SelectionChanged event in the code-behind file and delegate the call to the ViewModel.

The M-V-VM pattern is not about to eliminate ALL code from the code-behind file. It’s about separating of concerns - to put view logic into the ViewModel and let the view be as stupid as possible.

If you are interested in a concrete example then you might have a look at the ViewModel sample of the [**WPF Application Framework (WAF)**](http://waf.codeplex.com).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi - Thanks for the response. Yes, I do know that the idea of the MVVM is not to eliminate code from the code behind completely but I do believe there are other answers to this example that do not include code in the code behind. Perhaps the solution is AttachedBehavior. I'm still looking.

Comment: I was hoping to find something better but had no luck. I could use the MVVM Toolkit Light with Event To Command but ended up just delegating from the codebehind's SelectionChanged.
Thanks again jbe!

Comment: I have had success with the MVVM Light Toolkit's EventToCommand as part of an EventTrigger.  I had seen a sample by Laurent Bugnion and found it immensely helpful:  http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/12/17/silverlight-4-dragampdrop-with-eventtocommand.aspx

Admittedly I haven't used it in a datagrid scenario... just bound to other data templates.